# Amount of rows copied into new DataFrame is limited by exisitng number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several excel files from which I want to extract the data of given colum (each of different size) of each of them and copy it to a new Data Frame.
The way I did is to convert each excel to a data frame and then just copy them to the new df as follows:

```
df_final['Column_name'] = df_i['Column_name']  # df_final is the final dataframe, whereas df_i is one of the initial dataframes
```

I have observed that the amount of rows of the final dataframe is limited to the amount of columns of the first dataframe that I copied, so if the rest og dataframes have more rows of data, this information is not copied into the final data frame. Why is this happening? How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `pd.concat`:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1]})
pd2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
pd3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
your_dfs= [pd1, pd2, pd3]

pd_final = pd.concat(your_dfs, axis=1)

print(pd_final)
```

Comment: You can even combine all data frame at once, hence the list.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. However, OP suggested some sort of iteration, which I tried to implicitly cover in the example. But thanks, I will update it.

Comment: That's great! And would you happen to  know why my method didn't work for this and limits the amount of rows to the size of the first dataframe? Thanks!